Pass object parameter using Shell Navigation from xaml
How can I pass object parameter using MAUI Shell navigation? What I want is to navigate to the same View showing different title and loading different data according to an Enum that I am passing when I click the shell navigation.

I can achieve this using Shell.Current.GoToAsync():
   private async void Button1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       { "Type", AccountType.accountType.Customer },
   };
       await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(CustomersPage)}", navigationParameters);
   }

   private async void Button2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       
       var navigationParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       { "Type", AccountType.accountType.Dealer },
   };
       await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(CustomersPage)}", navigationParameters);

   }

But not using Flyout Shell Content Navigation.
        <ShellContent
                 Title="الصفحة الرئيسية"
                 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage}"
                 Route="HomePage" />

        <ShellContent
         Title="إدارة الزبائن"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:CustomersPage}"
         Route="CustomersPage" />
        
        <ShellContent
         Title="إدارة الموردين"
         ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:CustomersPage}"
         Route="DealersPage" />


Set the property in xaml:
 <ShellContent
                 Title="الصفحة الرئيسية"
                 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage}"
                 Route="HomePage" />

<ShellContent
 Title="إدارة الزبائن"
  Route="CustomersPage" >
    <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <view:CustomersPage Type="Customer" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
 </ShellContent>
 
<ShellContent
 Title="إدارة الموردين"
 ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:CustomersPage}"
 Route="DealersPage">
     <ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <view:CustomersPage Type="Dealer" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ShellContent.ContentTemplate>
 </ShellContent>

Note that your property Type have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged:
        AccountType type;
        public AccountType Type
        {
            get => type;
            set
            {
                type = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Type));
            }
        }


Thanks, but i am getting error on:
<view:CustomersPage Type="Customer" />
Type 'CustomersPage' is not usable as an object element because it is not public or does not define a public parameterless constructor or a type converter.

the error is self-explanatory; the class CustomersPage should be public and have a parameterless constructor CustomersPage() { }
